# How do I position a button in jQuery Mobile

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, css-float

How can I fix the position of the SignIn button to the right of the header even when the browser size changes. The SignIn button is inside a `<div>` I am using jQuery mobile 1.4.

[image: Mobile Header]

I have looked at all the answers but couldn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to put the button in a DIV, just give it a class of `"ui-btn-right"`.  See demo here: **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5FT6G/1/**

If you really want it inside a DIV, use the same class on the button and set the DIV to `"display: inline"`. Here is a demo of that: **http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/5FT6G/2/**